# Replace a backlash in string with the word backslash (Java)

Tags: java, string, replace, escaping, character

I have a string "My \n bio", and when I print this string the ouput is:

```
My 
 bio
```

What I want to accomplish is this output:

```
My backslash bio
```

I have read a lot of questions about escape characters in java and how to replace them, but I still can't get it right. I came up with these solutions:

```
string.replace("\\", "backslash");
string.replaceAll("\\\\", "backslash");
```

But when I print the string I get the same ouput as before. When I use

```
string.replace("\n", "backslash")
```

I get the desired output, but I want it to be more general. In short my question is: how to I replace all backslashes in a string with the word "backslash".

Comment: You are aware that the backslash character has a special meaning in a Java program?

Comment: Yeah, while it appears as two characters in a string, the '\n' sequence actually represents a single character: ASCII 10 / 0x0A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rather quick and simple method to replace some of java's escape sequences:

```
 static String replaceEscapes(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("\n", "<linefeed>")
        .replaceAll("\r", "<carriage return")
        .replaceAll("\t", "<tab>")
        .replaceAll("\b", "<backslash>")
        .replaceAll("\f", "<formfeed>");
  }
```

Comment: Good call.  Totally not needed.  I was thinking I could do some C# extension method and build a string character by character and then remembered I couldn't do it in Java... and then never took it out.  Yeah kill the loop.